# Highcharts Export-data: Show notes in the data table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts, I want to show different symbols next to point values to indicate certain notes. I use an additional attribute for the point ("note") and I can then use it in tooltips and dataLabels, as shown here:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Title'
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return "<strong>" + this.series.name + "</strong><br /><strong>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '' + '<b><sup>' + this.point.note + '</sup></b></strong>';
        }
    },

    credits: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        spacingBottom: 30
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010,
            dataLabels: {
                useHTML: true,
                enabled: true,
                allowOverlap: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    zIndex: 5

                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + "<sup>" + this.point.note.toLowerCase() + "</sup>";
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [{
            id: "myID",
            note: "",
            y: 12.22,
            value: 12.22
        }, {
            id: "myID",
            note: "",
            y: 13.11,
            value: 13.11
        }, {
            id: "myID",
            note: "*",
            y: 14.99,
            value: 14.99
        }]
    }],

    exporting: {
        showTable: true
    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/o3bmyu5d/10/

Now I want to use the Export-data module to allow the user to see the data in table form. This works well, as shown in the jsFiddle above, but how could I add the same symbols/notes I show in tooltips and dataLabels in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `keys` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys)) for the series, which is used when creating the table.

For example, in your case you can set keys as follows ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/myh1Ls9d/)):

```
series: [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    keys: ['y', 'note'],
    data: [...]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that will be helpful. I would not want to show an additional column, but if I create a single key (say, "display") that combines y + note, then I guess that would work? Would using just one key have an unexpected effect somewhere else? See: https://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/fcwhr8k9/9/

Comment: Looks good! It will affect your ability to use data points array without object. That is, you can't specify series data as `[5, 7, 3]`, as it will try to map it to match your `keys`. You have to use `[{ y: 5, ...}, { y: 7, ...}]`.

Comment: Not a problem for me, as I always use an object for data points. Thanks for your help!